# PHP script can't work with autoloaded classes

Tags: php, autoloader

The UsersView class object can't be loaded with the custom autoloader, finishing the PHP script with the following error. What would be the solution?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'UsersView' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/solent/common/registration/pendings.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/solent/common/registration/pendings.php on line 4
```

Project structure:

```
classes
   |_____ UsersView.php

common
   |_____ autoloader.php
   |_____ registration
               |_____ pendings.php
```

Pendings.php script

```php
include("../autoloader.php");

$pendingsView = new UsersView();
$rows = $pendingsView->getAllUsers();
```

Autoloader.php script

```php
spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');

    function myAutoLoader($className) {
        $path = "../classes";
        $extension = ".php";

        $fullPath = $path . $className . $extension;

        if(!file_exists($fullPath)) {
            return false;
        }

    include_once $fullPath;
```

Comment: In your structure, does the file have a `.php` extension and is the class called "UsersView"? Could use [get_included_files()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) to see if it was included

Comment: Looks like you are missing a slash... so try: `$fullPath = $path .'/'. $className . $extension;` or just edit `$path = "../classes/";` ... also make sure your include file has the extension of .php on the end, since in the "Project structure:" you show, its missing the .php on UsersView.

Comment: Did't help, it still complains with the same error, however the UsersView has the `.php` extension and additional `/` is added to the path